# How can I link a switch and a visible property by binding with a ViewModel?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a switch and a label on my XAML page:

```
<Switch x:Name="CpSwitch" Toggled="CpSwitch" />

<ViewCell x:Name="aBtn" Tapped="openPicker">
   <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="20, 0">
      <Label Text="Don't Know" />
      <Picker x:Name="aBtnPicker"  SelectedIndexChanged="aBtnPickerSelectedIndexChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Points}">
      </Picker>
      <Label Text="{Binding ABtnLabel}"/>
   </Grid>
</ViewCell>
```

My ViewModel

```
public class SettingsViewModel: ObservableProperty
{
    public SettingsViewModel()
    {
    }
```

What I would like to do is to use a ViewModel and in that view model have the switched state either make the ViewCell visible or not.

Can someone give me some suggestions on how I can bind the switch and the visible property for the ViewCell using a ViewModel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you bind them both to the same `Boolean` variable in your view model.

```
<Switch IsToggled="{Binding ShowViewCell}" />

<ViewCell IsVisible="{Binding ShowViewCell}">
   ...
</ViewCell>
```

And in your view model:

```
public class SettingsViewModel
{
    public bool ShowViewCell {get;set;}
}
```

This ensures that when the Switch is turned ON the ViewCell becomes visible. If you want to achieve the opposite you could write a custom converter:

```
public class InverseBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !(bool)value;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !(bool)value;
    }
}
```

Add it to your App.xaml resource dictionary:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <converters:InverseBoolConverter x:Key="InverseBoolConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

And apply that to the ViewCell:

```
<Switch IsToggled="{Binding ShowViewCell, Converter={StaticResource InverseBoolConverter}}" />
```

Comment: Could you not just add a `ShowViewCell = true` into the constructor of the view model?

Comment: Default value for a bool is false, so definitely recommend setting it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/default-values-table

can do so like this though

public bool ShowViewCell { get; set; } = true;